# Vim backup from remote server

Tags: vim

How do I automatically backup remote files after connecting via Putty or SSH?

Vim doesn't seem to create backup locally for those files...

Below is the setting for my vimrc

```
set backup
set backupdir=~/backup/
set dir=~/backup/
```

It works for my local files by the way.

Comment: What specific command line are you typing to start `vim` and edit files on the remote site? Are you using `netrw` to edit remote files via `scp`, `sftp`, `ftp`, `dav`, `http`, `rcp`, or similar protocols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use vim on the remote machine, you have to also set the settings there. You should copy your .vimrc to the other machine. One easy way for this is `scp ~/.vimrc user@server:~`

Comment: but vim is not installed on remote server and I'm just opening remote files via my local computer

Comment: So how are you opening the files? If you use vim _after_ connecting via Putty or ssh then you are using vim on the server.